# Trying to save the output from BabyAGI with Tools into the REST API Backend

Tags: reactjs, django, large-language-model, py-langchain

My code structure is:
React Frontend
-> Textfield saves the (string) input successfully into the REST API Backend (Django)
Django Backend
-> In the utils.py file there I have this function that is basically 1:1 copied from [here - Github](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/cookbook/baby_agi_with_agent.ipynb)
--> Basically my function looks like this:

```
def generateAgentAnswer(user_input):
    # Define your embedding model
    embeddings_model = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    embedding_size = 1536
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(embedding_size)
    vectorstore = FAISS(embeddings_model.embed_query, index, InMemoryDocstore({}), {})

    todo_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(
        "You are a planner who is an expert at coming up with a todo list for a given objective. Come up with a todo list for this objective: {objective}"
    )
    todo_chain = LLMChain(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0), prompt=todo_prompt)
    search = SerpAPIWrapper()
    tools = [
        Tool(
            name="Search",
            func=search.run,
            description="useful for when you need to answer questions about current events",
        ),
        Tool(
            name="TODO",
            func=todo_chain.run,
            description="useful for when you need to come up with todo lists. Input: an objective to create a todo list for. Output: a todo list for that objective. Please be very clear what the objective is!",
        ),
    ]

    prefix = """You are an AI who performs one task based on the following objective: {objective}. Take into account these previously completed tasks: {context}."""
    suffix = """Question: {task} {agent_scratchpad}"""
    prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
        tools,
        prefix=prefix,
        suffix=suffix,
        input_variables=["objective", "task", "context", "agent_scratchpad"],
    )

    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
    tool_names = [tool.name for tool in tools]
    agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, allowed_tools=tool_names)
    agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)

    OBJECTIVE = user_input

    # Logging of LLMChains
    verbose = False
    # If None, will keep on going forever
    max_iterations: Optional[int] = 3
    baby_agi = BabyAGI.from_llm(llm=llm, vectorstore=vectorstore, task_execution_chain=agent_executor, verbose=verbose, max_iterations=max_iterations)

    agi_Response = baby_agi({"objective": OBJECTIVE})

    return agi_Response
```

The views.py file looks like this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def agent_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        agents = Agent.objects.all()
        serializer = AgentSerializer(agents, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.data.get('user_messages', [])  # Assuming this sends a list of messages
        ai_response = generateAgentAnswer(user_input[0] if user_input else "")  # Getting the first message

        # Directly assign ai_response if you want it stored as a dictionary
        new_agent = Agent.objects.create(
            user_messages=user_input,  # Storing the whole list of user messages
            agent_messages=ai_response  # Storing the AI response directly
        )

        serializer = AgentSerializer(new_agent)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

and when I call the function in the shell it works flawlessly, but I can't save it into the REST API Backend. Or I can save it but it saves this output: "objective": "user input string from TextField" - It does not save the actual dictionary (because agi_Response is of type 'dict') that was generated from the function.

Any suggestions are appreciated.